# Creating two different posts types on my Gatsby site - rewriting my gatsby-node.js

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I need to identify the different markdown files I have so I can create a unique url structure for them. I can already identify "notes" files, and want to create a second type called "projects".

My gatsby-node.js file looks like this right now

```
const path = require('path');
const { createFilePath } = require('gatsby-source-filesystem');

// Look at every node when it is created
exports.onCreateNode = ({node, getNode, actions}) => {
    // Check for markdown nodes
    const { createNodeField } = actions;
    if(node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
        // Create a slug out of the markdown filepath name
        const slug = createFilePath({
            node,
            getNode,
            basePath: 'notes'
        });
        // Add the newly created slug to the node itself
        createNodeField({
            node,
            name: 'slug',
            value: `/note${slug}`
        });
    }
};

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      graphql(`
        {
          allMarkdownRemark {
            edges {
              node {
                fields {
                  slug
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `).then(result => {
        result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
          createPage({
            path: node.fields.slug,
            component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/note.js`),
            context: {
              // Data passed to context is available in page queries as GraphQL variables.
              slug: node.fields.slug,
            },
          })
        })
        resolve()
      })
    })
  };
```